# Remove shadow of keyboard in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

I have implemented custom keyboard in an application, but there is a shadow border at the top of keyboard which I need to remove.

Can anyone please tell me how can I remove or hide it?

steps which I followed :

I have implemented this view (subclass of UIView) for keyboard

I have created an object of this subclass and set to an inputView of an UITextfield

code :

```
CustomNumericKeyboard *num_keyboard = [[CustomNumericKeyboard alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, Screen_Width, 220)];
num_keyboard.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.txtSearch.inputView = num_keyboard;
```

image :
[image]

Comment: You're talking about something custom. How is anyone supposed to know the answer to this if you don't post any code/screenshot? Sometimes I am amazed by questions like these...

Comment: I am really sorry about that . But I am not able to upload the screenshot due to less reputation .

Comment: so you just figured that losing some reputation by posting an unanswerable question was a good idea?

Comment: @David I think he was being sarcastic

Comment: @Yagnesh by the way I found interesting your other question about `AVPlayer` and I upvoted it. Now you should have enough reputation to improve this question.

Comment: @YagneshLondhe upvoted your question just in case you lacked some reputation. Have a good day!

Comment: Thanx a lot . 

One thing I noticed that iOS default keyboard is also having the shadow border at the top . Can you please suggest me any solution to remove it or hide it . Please refer to this link  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101365479/forum%20image.png

Comment: Include the additional information (screenshot, code and further explanation about what you've done) to your question. Don't post it in comments

Comment: Code of CustomNumericKeyboard ? Or a least a link if you took it from a GitHub or else...

Comment: How can we help out unless you post some part of code and screenshot as well?

Answer (score 0):

self.txtSearch.inputAccessoryView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

Answer (score 0):

Search some sample code available on GitHub. This one might help [iOS custom keyboard](https://github.com/jp-dubey07/Custom-iOS-Keyboards)